# jQuery search thru ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an ajax GET call and returns some html, the return data is a wrapper and some content.Is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
$.ajax({
  url: appUrl+"/a/b/c/"+getId+"/"+getTime,
  success: function(data) {
   $(data).find('.shared').appendTo('.something');
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try that code? it should work just like that

Comment: I get this: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ....(html code from response)st.error jquery-latest.min.js:4
ft jquery-latest.min.js:4
wt jquery-latest.min.js:4
st jquery-latest.min.js:4
b.fn.extend.find jquery-latest.min.js:4
b.fn.b.init jquery-latest.min.js:3
b jquery-latest.min.js:3
$.ajax.success script.min.js:1
c jquery-latest.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery-latest.min.js:3
k jquery-latest.min.js:5
r

Comment: Might be worth doing some debugging `response = $(data).find('.shared'); console.log(response)`. This will let you see if the AJAX call is returning syntactically correct data.

Comment: I have added doctype body and html and now it works